# WKWebView incorrect content width in landscape with safe area

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

This is how it looks:
[image: wrong offsets and width]
Maximally simple code to reproduce:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    WKWebView* webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:[[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init]];
    self.view = webView;

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://apple.com"]]];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

@end
```

This happens only to the websites with `viewport-fit=cover` set. If you open same websites in Safari, you can see that first draw frame has the same problem, but it instantly resizes correctly after.

This happens only when launched in landscape.
Rotation to portrait and back to landscape fixes this. Even minimizing app and opening it again fixes this.

So is there anything I can do from code to force it fix itself? 
I've already tried calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` to whole `WKWebView` tree. Setting scroller insets will make content look like it doesn't have `viewport-fit=cover` set.
This happens on iOS 12 and 13 (tested) and iOS 13 Simulator.

Comment: you need to set the wkwebview frame size, or use constraints to adjust the size

Comment: it is main view of view controller, it is sized correctly covering whole screen. scroller inside also covers whole screen. WKContentView's width is smaller than the screen by the sum of safe area's left and right offsets. And the same thing happens with the constraints anyways.

Comment: have you tried calling the loadView in viewDidappear?

Comment: loadView is being called a little earlier by the system, if I would call it from viewDidappear it would create second WKWebView and remove the first one. Anyway I tried it with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the perfect solution but I managed to fix this by adding the webView as subView to self.view and add constraints to superview instead of safeArea to get the same effect.

Solution:

- Connect trailing constraint to a variable
- Set constraint isEnabled to
  false in viewDidLoad (to optimize check for deviceOrientation)
- In function webView(WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation) set constraint isEnabled to true
- Don't forget to register to navigationDelegate of the webView

  ```
  @IBOutlet var mainWebView: WKWebView!
  @IBOutlet var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
      if orientation == .landscapeLeft || orientation == .landscapeRight {
          trailingConstraint.isActive = false
      }

      mainWebView.navigationDelegate = self
      mainWebView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com")!))
  }

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      trailingConstraint.isActive = true
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the missing puzzle piece. I actually added all of the constraints at the start, then deactivated trailing one in didFinish navigation, and activated it again. And it looks the same as in Safari.

Comment: The point is to force the webView to redraw after the page is loaded (some sort of scenario that happens when deviceOrientation changes).

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I have the same problem but with the vertical safe area in portrait orientation. Any Ideas?

Comment: Anyone figure this out? Same issues in SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, You need to change viewport.**

*Please change your "loadView" function with below code.*

```
- (void)loadView
{
    NSString *jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

    WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
    WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    [wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController;

    WKWebView* webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:wkWebConfig];
    webView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false;
    webView.scrollView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false;
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.view = webView;

    UIWindow *window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows.firstObject;
    CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
    CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
    CGFloat leftPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.left;
    CGFloat rightPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.right;
    self.additionalSafeAreaInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(-topPadding, -leftPadding, -bottomPadding, -rightPadding);
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://apple.com"]]];
}
```

Comment: this only centers webpage, but doesn't make it fullscreen

Comment: you need to remove safe area insets.

Comment: Still not correct, check apple logo and shopping icon offsets in the header, some text is covered by notch as well - https://i.imgur.com/eRwzeL4.png
And this is how it's supposed to look - https://i.imgur.com/cb9H0Q7.png (and it looks the same in Safari)